# how to clear the fragment stack and activity stack on a button click

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

There are similar questions, but none of the are solving my issue.
My app flow is following:

Activity home starts Activity B(which does the setup work)
In activity B hosts three screens as fragments...
Fragment1 -> fragment2-> fragment 3.

This is how I make fragments. I am not using replace.just adding it.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        Fragment fragment = null;
        if (getFragType().equals("simple")) {
            fragment = new SimpleFragment().newInstance();
        }
        if (getFragType.equals("inter")) {
            if (getFragType.getComponent().equals("con"))
                fragment = new SetupConFragment().newInstance();
            else if (getFragType.getComponent().equals("ben"))
                fragment = new SetupBenageFragment().newInstance();
        }
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
```

Fragment3 has a done button. So once all the 3 steps are done from fragment 3  am launching a new activity C.

The issue is:--
From the activity C , if the user presses the back button, it diplays fragment 2, then fragment 1. Ideally once the user is in Activity C, back press should just exit the screen
I have used all combinations of the intent flags, but it is not helping.

And this is on my button click.

```
Intent launch = new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class);
                    launch.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    launch.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    launch.putExtra("Exit me", true);
                    mContext.startActivity(launch);
                    ((ConfigureActivity)mContext).finish();
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Calling finish() on Activity B should remove it from the back stack. Where should the focus go if the user presses the back button in Activity C?

Comment: ConfigureActivity is my activity B, ideally it should.But seems there is a miss somewhere. Clearing backtrace is not working(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this way:

**Clear Fragment stack**:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

**Clear Activity stack**:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Your_Current_Activity.this, Your_Destination_Activity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank You tons Hiren, it worked :-) Strange thing is , I have given same options in two different statements, and it was not working, pipe sign however worked. I just used  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK) and all associated fragment tasks are cleared..Voteup and answer accepted.

Comment: @simon glad to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Say, if you want to start Activity B in Activity A but you don't want user to go back to Activity A,

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
startActivity();
finish(); // kill the current activity (i.e., Activity A) so user cannot go back
```

Comment: I think you havent seen my post full, thats what I am doing....my issue is to clear the stack.

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity C, you can control Back key by overriding `onBackPressed()`.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
     // code here depending on your needs
}
```

Comment: yeps, but that is not solving this issue. I can simply ignore the super.onBackPressed() there but I want to remove the complete fragment stack.