# Clear framgnetBackStack when particular fragment was opened

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to clear the backstack when I open one particular Fragment.
Lets assume that I have Fragment Foo and Fragment Bar, that I can open in MainActivity. Also, I can open other fragments from Foo or Bar.
This is the simple scheme:

Main Activity - Foo-> Foo1-> Foo2-> Foo3

Main Activity - Bar-> Bar1-> Bar2-> Bar3

Also, I have a menu, so I can access Fragments Foo and Bar from any place: e.i it can be reached from Foo2 or Bar3 or any other Fragment.
The thing is that I want to CLEAR the backstack when I enter Foo or Bar after this Fragment was opened.

Main Activity - Foo-> Foo1-> Foo2-> Foo3 - > Bar

(clear the backstack, so back button would close the app).

I'm trying to close all fragments by doing like that:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    for(int i = 0; i < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); ++i) {
        fm.popBackStack();
    }
}
```

And manipulations is this order:
Main Activity - Foo-> Foo1-> Foo2-> Foo3 - > Bar.
But when Bar Fragment should appears I see Foo Fragment only.
Without clearing the backstack all seems to work fine, except back button returns previous Foo3 Fragment.
So, what I'm doing wrong?

Also, I'v done clearing by:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

but it doesn't work either.

Comment: can you please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31737013/how-to-clear-the-fragment-stack-and-activity-stack-on-a-button-click one. I have given same answer.

Comment: your way produces the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear backstack only in activity, before you open any fragment.